# First match after match

Tags: awk

Given [this file](http://cygwin.osuosl.org/x86_64/setup.ini), I would like to
print the first `install:` line that comes after the `@ bash` line. Please see
the file for complete input, but here is a sample

```
@ base-files
; few lines
install: x86_64/release/base-files/base-files-4.2-3.tar.xz 46428 6372358800e589b
; couple of lines
install: x86_64/release/base-files/base-files-4.1-1.tar.bz2 49519 f91ed6eab060c3

@ bash
; few lines
install: x86_64/release/bash/bash-4.1.17-9.tar.xz 1107128 e49b8d67d59d8617dfa31c
; couple of lines
install: x86_64/release/bash/bash-4.1.16-8.tar.xz 1106812 5aa652ddc0a5d65f4af1e2
source: x86_64/release/bash/bash-4.1.16-8-src.tar.xz 6614280 79bb3ddc67d8f0d3da6

@ bash-completion
; few lines
install: x86_64/release/bash-completion/bash-completion-1.3-1.tar.bz2 117489 538
source: x86_64/release/bash-completion/bash-completion-1.3-1-src.tar.bz2 216503
```

Output should be

```
install: x86_64/release/bash/bash-4.1.17-9.tar.xz 1107128 e49b8d67d59d8617dfa...
```

I have this command, but it prints all lines inclusive of the two.

```
awk '/@ bash$/,/install:/' setup.ini
```

In addition to the answers I created this one

```
awk '$1=="@" {c=$2} $1=="install:" && c=="bash" {print;exit}'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk '/@ bash$/{p=1} p&&/install:/{print; exit}' setup.ini
install: x86_64/release/bash/bash-4.1.17-9.tar.xz 1107128 e49b8d67d59d8617dfa31c
```

Comment: You must have been reading over my shoulder — even down to the name of the variable!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I like the `exit`, it might help with large files

Comment: Yes I find it funny that we ended up using same variable name. `p` seems to be my favorite `awk` variable name (don't know why). But `exit` does speedup in case input file is large after this line.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '/^@ bash/ { p = 1 } /^install:/ && p == 1 { print; p = 2 }'
```

The variable `p` defaults to 0; when the `@ bash` line is read, set it to 1; when the next install line is read, print it and set p to 2 so no other install lines will be printed.  You could also exit instead of setting `p = 2`, I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '$1=="@" {c=$2} $1=="install:" && c=="bash" {print;exit}'
```

- If field one is `@`, save field two to variable `c`
- If field one is `install:` and `c` is `bash`, print and exit